# Boost.IOStreams: 'file_descriptor_sink' accepts empty string as pathname; should I guard against that?

Tags: c++, string, file, boost, boost-iostreams

I develop a library that internally uses Boost.IOStreams.  Recently, I hit an interesting corner case with [`file_descriptor_sink`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/iostreams/doc/index.html).  It looks like doing

```
file_descriptor_sink s("");
```

or

```
file_descriptor_sink s;
s.open("");
```

is perfectly valid and `s.is_open()` definitely returns `true` afterwards.  For me, this is a complete nonsense.  That is to what file is it open?

Two questions in this regard:

1. Is there any function that I could use to detect this condition?  To elaborate, when I first hit this case, I immediately recalled that the following holds:

   ```
   ofstream ofs("");
   assert(!ofs);
   assert(!ofs.is_open());
   assert(ofs.fail());
   ```

   what is clearly opposite to the `file_descriptor_sink` behavior in terms of `is_open` and `fail` is not even available.  Otherwise, I'd have to directly test for empty string (pathname) before construction of `file_descriptor_sink` in order to track this condition.
2. Do you agree that throwing well-forged exception to a user of the library in this case would be a good idea?  I was thinking about [`std::system_error`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/system_error) with the [`bad_file_descriptor`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/errc) error code.

Comment: What platform?  I think you should step through this in a debugger.  The path appears to get passed to `CreateFile` (windows) or `open` (not Windows) - which don't (I think) allow empty strings.

Comment: I suggest you ask about this on the boost mailing list - they may well be able to give a better answer.

Comment: @Martin Bonner, might be good idea, thanks.